# How to convert milliseconds to date string in swift 3

Tags: ios, swift3

I am trying to convert milliseconds to date string in swift 3,i tried by setting date fomatter but i am not getting current date string.

```
var milliseconds=1477593000000

let date = NSDate(timeIntervalSince1970: TimeInterval(milliseconds))
let formatter = DateFormatter()
formatter.dateFormat = "dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss"
formatter.locale = NSLocale(localeIdentifier: "en_US") as Locale!
print(formatter.string(from: date as Date))

output:

22-01-48793 01:30:00
```

Comment: try `TimeInterval(milliseconds / 1000)` and check output

Comment: i tried by dividing with 1000 it is working

Answer (score 39, accepted):

*Try this*,

```
var date = Date(timeIntervalSince1970: (1477593000000 / 1000.0))
print("date - \(date)")
```

You will get **output** as date :

> date - 2016-10-27 18:30:00 +0000

Answer (score 16):

How about trying this -

```
    let milisecond = 1479714427
    let dateVar = Date.init(timeIntervalSinceNow: TimeInterval(milisecond)/1000)
    var dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "dd-MM-yyyy hh:mm"
    print(dateFormatter.string(from: dateVar))
```

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/nsdate/1416453-init) of `NSDate`:

```
convenience init(timeIntervalSince1970 secs: TimeInterval)
```

> Returns an `NSDate` object initialized relative to the current date and time by a given number of seconds.

Just convert your milliseconds to seconds and you should get the correct date.