# Convert AVAudioTime to Date in Swift

Tags: swift, date, audio, avfoundation

How do I convert the `AVAudioTime` passed to an AVFoundation `installTap` render callback to an absolute host time that's in Swift `Date` format?

Comment: I think apple does provide `class func seconds(forHostTime hostTime: UInt64) -> TimeInterval` https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avaudiotime/1386096-seconds and then https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40714893/how-to-convert-milliseconds-to-date-string-in-swift-3 for changing it to date format.

Comment: The time `TimeInterval` returned by `AVAudioTime.seconds(forHostTime:)` is not an absolute date.

Comment: Yes it will return `TimeInterval` (Double value-Timestamp), which we can convert into date-format with https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40714893/how-to-convert-milliseconds-to-date-string-in-swift-3

Comment: The ticks returned by `AVAudioTime.seconds(forHostTime:)` is not the number of ticks since 1970, so if you pass it into `Date(timeIntervalSince1970: ...)`, I seem to get a time relative to when recording started, not an absolute date.

Comment: you can use `Date(timeIntervalSinceNow: <TimeInterval>)` or `Date(timeInterval: <TimeInterval>, since: <Date>)`.

Comment: Did you find any solution for this?